# Jasper report list element produces extra page

Tags: jasper-reports

Here are some screen shots to demonstrate the problem:
First, here is the design with no list element:

[image]

And here is the result of that report (note that there are two pages):

[image]

Now if I add the list element, here is the design:

[image]

Here is the jrxml for the summary band:

```
<summary>
        <band height="554">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$F{drawingRevision}.getPartsList().isEmpty() || !$F{drawingRevision}.getProcesses().isEmpty() || !$F{drawingRevision}.getParameters().isEmpty()]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="80" y="30" width="100" height="20" uuid="3210d220-35e0-4984-a00d-be4ad58feca4"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Static Text]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <rectangle radius="5">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="284" height="16" backcolor="#E1E3FC" uuid="88870baf-afe8-4c0a-9b5f-fe88eb0f4dd3"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="113" height="16" uuid="9231dea5-26f2-40a8-8b45-2ce560e0f2ba"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Design Parameters]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="16" width="284" height="13" uuid="12a8a577-6c77-4849-84c6-362544413192">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value="Parameters"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="DrawingRevisionParameters" uuid="5ff517f3-e25b-4ed5-8589-33076f52c2c2">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{drawingRevision}.getParameters())]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="13" width="284">
                        <textField pattern="#,##0.####">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="12" uuid="9239498a-9b30-495f-a571-b505fceba75a"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                <font size="9"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{parameter}.getParameterValue()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="54" y="0" width="72" height="12" uuid="f2c8d327-e8b4-4f5b-af0c-dad19c0fc4bb"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font size="9"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{parameter}.getParameterUnit().getUnitAbbr()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="132" y="0" width="150" height="12" uuid="0e48fb28-af4b-4fac-8069-63bc1f880d80"/>
                            <textElement markup="rtf">
                                <font size="9"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{parameter}.getSpecification().getSpecificationName()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
```

And finally here is the result of that report.

[image]

Note that the floating "Static Text" label moved down appropriately, but not nearly enough to add an extra page to the report.  However, you'll see that there are now 3 pages to the report anyway.

The only thing that changed was adding the list element.  How can I make it so that it doesn't add the extra page?  Or what am I not understanding with regard to lists?  I could probably also pass the data into a sub-report so that the data is presented in the detail band of the sub-report, but I would much prefer to use a list if I could, since it seems much simpler to me.  I am using version 6.6.0.  Thanks!

Here is the full jrxml as requested (uuids removed to save on characters):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Drawing" pageWidth="792" pageHeight="612" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="752" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" whenResourceMissingType="Error">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <subDataset name="DrawingRevisionNotes">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="orderNum" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[orderNum]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="drawingNote" class="com.engineering.domain.drawings.DrawingNote">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[drawingNote]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="DrawingApprovals">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="revisionID" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[revisionID]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="drafter" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[drafter]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="approver" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[approver]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="approvalDate" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[approvalDate]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="DrawingRevisionParameters">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="drawingParameterID" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[drawingParameterID]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="parameter" class="com.engineering.domain.drawings.DrawingParameter">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[parameter]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="orderNum" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[orderNum]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["static/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="draftCount" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[draftCount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="releaseType" class="com.engineering.domain.drawings.DrawingReleaseType">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[releaseType]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="releaser" class="com.humanresources.domain.Employee">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[releaser]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="releaseTimeStamp" class="java.time.LocalDateTime">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[releaseTimeStamp]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="company" class="com.companies.domain.Company">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[company]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="unitSystem" class="com.utilities.domain.units.UnitSystem">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[unitSystem]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="drawingReleaseID" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[drawingReleaseID]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="fullDescription" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[fullDescription]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="drawingRevision" class="com.engineering.domain.drawings.DrawingRevision">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[drawingRevision]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band height="554" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle radius="5">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="752" height="553"/>
            </rectangle>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="485" y="443" width="267" height="110">
                    <property name="ShowOutOfBoundContent" value="false"/>
                </reportElement>
                <rectangle radius="5">
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="267" height="110"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="34"/>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"HeaderSmall.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="35" width="180" height="1"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="39" y="36" width="21" height="7"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="5"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Title]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="44" y="40" width="136" height="47"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getTitle()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="39" y="90" width="21" height="7"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="5"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Drawing]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="44" y="94" width="136" height="16"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[String.format("%06d",$F{drawingRevision}.getDrawing().getDrawingID())+" Rev "+$F{drawingRevision}.getRevision().getRevisionID()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="38" y="36" width="1" height="74"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="1" height="110"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="39" y="89" width="141" height="1"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="36" width="37" height="74"/>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="2" y="2" width="33" height="7"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                            <font size="5" isItalic="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Tolerances]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="2" y="9" width="33" height="20"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                            <font size="5" isItalic="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{unitSystem}.getUnitTolerance().getUnit().getUnitNamePlural()+"\nUnless\nNoted"]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="2" y="29" width="33" height="33"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                            <font size="5" isItalic="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{unitSystem}.getUnitTolerance().getTolerance3Place()!=null ? "X.XXX ±"+$F{unitSystem}.getUnitTolerance().getTolerance3Place()+"\n" : "")+
($F{unitSystem}.getUnitTolerance().getTolerance2Place()!=null ? "X.XX ±"+$F{unitSystem}.getUnitTolerance().getTolerance2Place()+"\n" : "")+
($F{unitSystem}.getUnitTolerance().getTolerance1Place()!=null ? "X.X ±"+$F{unitSystem}.getUnitTolerance().getTolerance1Place()+"\n" : "")+
($F{unitSystem}.getUnitTolerance().getFractional()!=null ? "Frac. ±"+$F{unitSystem}.getUnitTolerance().getFractional()+"\n" : "")+
"Ang. ±30'"]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="87" height="109"/>
                    <componentElement>
                        <reportElement x="3" y="14" width="81" height="9">
                            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value="Approvals"/>
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getRevision().getRevisionType().getRevisionTypeID()==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                            <datasetRun subDataset="DrawingApprovals">
                                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{drawingRevision}.getApprovals())]]></dataSourceExpression>
                            </datasetRun>
                            <jr:listContents height="9" width="81">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="17" height="9"/>
                                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                        <font size="7"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{revisionID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="17" y="0" width="17" height="9"/>
                                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                        <font size="7"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{drafter}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                    <reportElement x="34" y="0" width="17" height="9"/>
                                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                        <font size="7"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{approver}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                    <reportElement x="51" y="0" width="30" height="9"/>
                                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                        <font size="7"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{approvalDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:listContents>
                        </jr:list>
                    </componentElement>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="3" y="3" width="17" height="11">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getRevision().getRevisionType().getRevisionTypeID()==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[REV]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="20" y="3" width="17" height="11">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getRevision().getRevisionType().getRevisionTypeID()==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[BY]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="37" y="3" width="17" height="11">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getRevision().getRevisionType().getRevisionTypeID()==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[APV]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="54" y="3" width="30" height="11">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getRevision().getRevisionType().getRevisionTypeID()==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[DATE]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                        <reportElement x="3" y="14" width="81" height="0">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getRevision().getRevisionType().getRevisionTypeID()!=1]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["PRELIMINARY REVISION "+$F{drawingRevision}.getRevision().getRevisionID()]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="3" y="17" width="82" height="1">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getRevision().getRevisionType().getRevisionTypeID()!=1]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <graphicElement>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </graphicElement>
                    </line>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="3" y="20" width="82" height="0">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getRevision().getRevisionType().getRevisionTypeID()!=1]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="7"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["REV  BY  APV  DATE\n   -     "+$F{drawingRevision}.getDrafter().getInitials()]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="554" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="RetainShape">
                <reportElement x="5" y="5" width="742" height="548"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["\\\\SERVER\\Data\\Design Files\\Drawings\\ERP Draft Images\\"+String.format("%05d",$F{drawingRevision}.getDrawing().getDrawingID())+$F{drawingRevision}.getRevision().getRevisionID()+($F{draftCount}>1 ? "p"+$F{draftCount} : "")+".jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="4" y="420" width="400" height="30">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value="Notes"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="DrawingRevisionNotes">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{drawingRevision}.getNotes())]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="400">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="48" height="14"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[NOTES]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="14" width="15" height="14"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{orderNum}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                            <reportElement x="16" y="14" width="384" height="14"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingNote}.getNoteText()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="485" y="405" width="267" height="38">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getMaterial()!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <rectangle radius="5">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="267" height="38"/>
                </rectangle>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="4" y="0" width="100" height="13"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Material]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="4" y="12" width="259" height="1"/>
                </line>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="138" y="0" width="61" height="13"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Coating]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="199" y="0" width="64" height="13"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Notes]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="4" y="13" width="134" height="24"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getMaterial().getMaterialRaw().getShortDescriptionNoCondition() + ( $F{drawingRevision}.getMaterial().getMaterialRaw().getMaterialCondition() == null || $F{drawingRevision}.getMaterial().getMaterialRaw().getMaterialCondition().getConditionDescription() == null || $F{drawingRevision}.getMaterial().getMaterialRaw().getMaterialCondition().getConditionDescription().trim() == "" ? "" : ", "+$F{drawingRevision}.getMaterial().getMaterialRaw().getMaterialCondition().getConditionDescription() )]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="138" y="13" width="61" height="24"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getMaterial().getMaterialCoating()==null ? "" : $F{drawingRevision}.getMaterial().getMaterialCoating().getCoatingDescription()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="199" y="13" width="64" height="24"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="6"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{drawingRevision}.getMaterial().getMaterialNotes()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="12" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="418" height="12"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{releaseTimeStamp}+"   Release ID: "+$F{drawingReleaseID}+"     "+$F{company}.getCompanyName()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="430" y="0" width="257" height="12"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[This proprietary drawing shall not be shared without written permission.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="687" y="0" width="50" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="737" y="0" width="15" height="12"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="554">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$F{drawingRevision}.getPartsList().isEmpty() || !$F{drawingRevision}.getProcesses().isEmpty() || !$F{drawingRevision}.getParameters().isEmpty()]]></printWhenExpression>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="467" y="1" width="284" height="318">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$F{drawingRevision}.getParameters().isEmpty()]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <rectangle radius="5">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="284" height="16" backcolor="#E1E3FC"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="113" height="16"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Design Parameters]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="16" width="284" height="13">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value="Parameters"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="DrawingRevisionParameters">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{drawingRevision}.getParameters())]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:listContents height="13" width="284">
                            <textField pattern="#,##0.####">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="12"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{parameter}.getParameterValue()]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="54" y="0" width="72" height="12"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{parameter}.getParameterUnit().getUnitAbbr()]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="132" y="0" width="150" height="12"/>
                                <textElement markup="rtf">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{parameter}.getSpecification().getSpecificationName()]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:listContents>
                    </jr:list>
                </componentElement>
            </frame>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="560" y="319" width="100" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Static Text]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Post the full JRXML if possible.

Comment: @DaveJarvis I added the full jrxml.  Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered this before and the fixes I did was.

1. Check the size of the detail band and make sure that the list of values generated can all fit into the same page. Reduce the size of the detail band to see the difference.
2. Another is hide bands that are not in use or empty. For example try hiding the Summary band by setting it's Print When Expression to Boolean.FALSE.
3. You can also go to Report Properties > Check off Ignore Pagination Property